# Rename folder with name consisting of multiple words

Tags: bash

For begining i have such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *; do
if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    if [ "$i" == $(grep $i names.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ]; then
        mv $i $(grep $i names.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    else
        echo "The word $i wasn't found in the dictionary"
    fi
fi
done
```

which renames files with dictionary (names.txt) which line is of pattern "english_word german_one".

```
one eins
two zwei
my mein
your dein
```

The problem is: it works only for files which names are one-wordish. "one" becomes "eins",
"two" becomes "zwei", but "one two" doesn't become "eins zwei".
How do I rename files with names consisting more than one word, e.g "My documents", "first folder", etc?
I know that I must somehow tokenize the folder name, but don't get how. New to the bash.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure Bash solution that is rather general: we'll tokenize the folder name and then perform the translation on each word found in the name. Before that, we'll load the dictionary into a hash array:

```
#!/bin/bash

# load dictionary
declare -A dictionary=()
while read -r eng ger; do
    [[ $eng ]] && [[ $ger ]] || continue
    dictionary[$eng]=$ger
done < dictionary_file

tokenize() {
    # Split $1 into two arrays:
    # tokenize_sep consists of all the non-alpha strings
    # tokenize_alpha consists of all the alpha strings
    # We have: $1=${tokenize_sep[0]}${tokenize_alpha[0]}${tokenize_sep[1]}${tokenize_alpha[1]} ...
    local var=$1
    tokenize_sep=() tokenize_alpha=()
    while [[ $var ]]; do
        [[ $var =~ ([^[:alpha:]]*)(.*) ]]
        tokenize_sep+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        [[ $var =~ ([[:alpha:]]*)(.*) ]]
        tokenize_alpha+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    done
}

translate_ary() {
    # Translates each word given as arguments according to hash array dictionary
    # Returned array is translate_ary_ret
    local w t
    translate_ary_ret=()
    for w; do
        if [[ $w ]]; then
            t=${dictionary[$w]}
            [[ $t ]] || t=$w
        else
            t=
        fi
        translate_ary_ret+=( $t )
    done
}

intertwine() {
    # $1 and $2 are two array names
    # returns a string intertwine_ret that consists of all fields of $1 and $2 intertwined (shuffled)
    local ary1=$1[@] ary2=$2[@] i
    ary1=( "${!ary1}" ) ary2=( "${!ary2}" )
    intertwine_ret=
    for((i=0;i<${#ary1[@]};++i)); do
        intertwine_ret+=${ary1[i]}${ary2[i]}
    done
}

translate() {
    # Translates string given in $1, preserving separators
    # Return string in translate_ret
    tokenize "$1"
    translate_ary "${tokenize_alpha[@]}"
    intertwine tokenize_sep translate_ary_ret
    translate_ret=$intertwine_ret
}

# Do the renaming:

for i in *; do
    translate "$i"
    [[ $i = "$translate_ret" ]] && continue
    echo mv -nv -- "$i" "$translate_ret"
done
```

It's not really a one-liner, but should do the job.

I called this script `banana`, `chmod +x` it and:

```
$ ls -1
banana
banana_is_my_favorite_fruit
dictionary_file
--one..my^ your-banana.one
one_two_bananas
your_two...pdf
$ ./banana
mv -nv -- banana_is_my_favorite_fruit banana_is_mein_favorite_fruit
mv -nv -- --one..my^ your-banana.one --eins..mein^ dein-banana.eins
mv -nv -- one_two_bananas eins_zwei_bananas
mv -nv -- your_two...pdf dein_zwei...pdf
```

Nothing has been moved: for this, remove the `echo` in front of the `mv` command at the bottom of the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`perl rename/prename`](http://man.cx/prename) command & awk at your disposal, try this one-liner:

```
$ touch one; mkdir -p "one two" two # "one two" & two are directories, one is file.

$ ls -F # verify. This would probably how your structure look like.
names.txt  one  "one two/"  two/  #<~~~~"one two" quoted only for the explanation. ls does not quote it.

$ prename "$(awk '{printf "s/"$1"/"$2"/g;"}' names.txt )" */ # This will rename as per your requirement.

$ ls -F # verify
"eins zwei/"  names.txt  one  zwei/ #<~~~~ same quoting here too...
```

Explanation:

```
$ awk '{printf "s/"$1"/"$2"/g;"}' names.txt # generates the find/replace perl regex.
s/one/eins/g;s/two/zwei/g;s/my/mein/g;s/your/dein/g;
```

`prename` then renames the files supplied using the perl-regex.

`*/` glob specifies only directories, viz "one two" & "two", ignoring the file "one".

Answer (score 0):

Use proper quoting

```
 mv "$i" "$(grep $i names.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
```

The  double quotes will take care of the spaces in the filenames

Comment: thanks for response. But that didn't work
It again renamed one-wordish folders, but multiple-wordish stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

After kicking google for a while, I came to such solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    newname=""
    del=""
    for word in $i; do
        if [ "$word" == "$(grep $word names.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" ]; then
            newname="$newname""$del""$(grep $word names.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
        else
            newname="$newname""$del""$word"
        fi
        del=" "
    done
    if [ "$i" != "$newname" ]; then 
        mv "$i" "$newname"
    fi
fi
done
```